# Find primitive element of splitting field of $1 + x + x^2 - x^5$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, splitting-field

As the title says, I need to find the primitive element of the splitting field of $1 + x + x^2 - x^5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Firstly, I would proceed by finding the roots as the splitting field has to contain all the roots. So I rewrite the polynomial as: $$-(x^2+1)(x^3-x-1)$$
But here things get awful really quick - apart from the obvious roots $\pm i$, the roots of the cubic are far from being something nice.

Am missing some smart idea on how to avoid such nasty expressions when solving the problem?

**UPDATE**

The polynomial is a characteristic polynomial of an integer 5x5 matrix with determinant 1 and zero trace. Would some transformation of my matrix possibly help?

Comment: Just to make this particular cubic more familar: [Plastic constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlasticConstant.html)

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?

Comment: Earth to NumberFour, come in, please!

Comment: Gerry, many thanks for your answer! I spent some time on this, but in the end I realized this exercise was meant to be done entirely symbolically. Following the idea from the example on Wiki article "Primitive element theorem", one has to write primitive element $\gamma\prime = \alpha_1 + \beta_1$ where $\alpha_1$ is the first root of the quadratic and $\beta_1$ of the cubic. Then adjoining the cubic's second root $\beta_2$ to this field. In the end one of the proper primitive elements of the splitting field is: $\gamma = \alpha_1 + \beta_1 + 2\beta_2$. Anyway, I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Conjugate roots $\bar{\alpha_1}$ and $\bar{\beta_2}$ should belong to this field automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of the cubic. The discriminant of the cubic is $-23$ (I think --- better check this), so the splitting field of the cubic is ${\bf Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{-23})$. Then the splitting field of the polynomial is ${\bf Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{-23},i)$. The chances are that $\alpha+\sqrt{-23}+i$ is a primitive element (not **the** primitive element, there's no such thing). Try to prove that it has degree 12.